# how to obtain specific numbers using some processes on given number?

Tags: arithmetic

With a natural number, the following processes can be used:

1. Type 0 at the right of the given number
2. Type number 4 to the right of the given number
3. Divide the number to 2

If number 55 is given, can the following numbers be obtained: 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007

((((( if we obtain number 32 then we can obtain any of this numbers: 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007 )))

THANKS ALOT

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: Can you obtain $27.5$ by dividing $55$ by $2$, even though that doesn't result in an integer?

Comment: there is no source, just i got this question from a friend!

Comment: no we cannot obtain 27.5 .. we just can obtain integer numbers.

Comment: So, where did your friend get the question, please?

Comment: it's from an mathematical Olympiad on our country

Comment: the solution is with 27 steps .. we have to go from 55 to 32 then it's easy

Comment: If you now know how to solve the problem, let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer, for anyone who comes along later.

Comment: no i do not know, but i write an c# program to solve that problem, it's need 3^28 process to solve it. so it's taking so ling time
----
example: from 32 to 2003 : 32,320,3204,1602,16024,8012,4006,2003